# Efficiently incrementing table cell with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

This should be simple. The key word in the title is "efficiently".

I have:

```
<td id="pieceCount">13</td>
```

and I want to increment the cell value by 14. The cell will always only contain integers. To do this, I currently have:

```
$("#pieceCount").text(parseInt($("#pieceCount").text()) + 14);
```

and that works well. However, it seems inefficient to send jQuery looking for `#pieceCount` twice.

Is there a way I can use `this` or `$(this)` within the outer `text()` call to refer to the `#pieceCount` element jQuery has already found? Or perhaps there is another technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, reuse selectors where possible:

```
var $e = $("#pieceCount");
$e.text(~~$e.text()+ 14);
```

Also `~~` is a fast shortcut for integer conversion

You can also pass a function to `text` like this:

```
$("#pieceCount").text(function(){ return ~~$(this).text()+14 });
```

Note: As `@Archer` points out you can address the inner text using the `innerText` property of the raw DOM element, but I tend to fallback on jQuery for insulation (and intellisense in VS). and as `@A. Wolff` points out, the existing text value is passed as an argument to any function passed to `text()`.

```
$("#pieceCount").text(function(i, t){ return ~~t+14 });
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function

Comment: Ninja'd, so +1, and nice use of ~~ which I didn't actually know about.  Thanks :)

Comment: `~~` is freaky interesting. Do you have a reference to it you can add?

Comment: @Jonathan M: Apparently it is hard to Google for `~~`. If I find a reference I will add it :)

Comment: @Jonathan M: And you can always fallback to using a `+` prefx on a string to convert it.

Comment: @A. Wolff: Thanks for the reference :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, thanks, mate. I'm a little surprised that you can't do something like: `$("#pieceCount").text(~~$(this).text() + 14);`. With that code, I get `NaN`. What is `this` in that context?

Comment: If you provide a non-function to `text` (as per your example) the `this` is the current `this` where the code is called. Same as doing `var t = ~~$(this).text();` then `.text(t + 14)` if you see what I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly what you suggest by using a function inside `text()`...

```
$("#pieceCount").text(function() { return parseInt(this.innerText, 10) + 14; });
```

And here's a working example (I used a div for simplicity)...

https://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/dqkcunno/

Comment: So, here `this` is referring directly to the DOM element and not a jQuery object?

Comment: Yes.  Typically any jQuery function has `this` as a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: @Jonathan M: `this` is usually the raw DOM element in most jQuery functions.

Comment: @JonathanM Ya, but you could use instead function parameter: `.text(function(_, txt){ return +txt + 14;});`